# Error when compiling: header file name conflict with standard library math.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is a problem that happens to me from a large project and that i have managed to make it as simple as possible to post it in here. I am using Visual studio 2015 so i wonder if its a problem with the compiler/IDE anyway.

I got a custom static C library that has a header file called "Math.h", when wanting to use this library in a C++ project and add my static library's include directory to the project, there it seems the standard library is trying to use my Math.h file first and i got these errors:

```
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'fabs': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(27): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'fabsf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2039: 'acosf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C3861: 'acosf': identifier not found
```

I can produce this problem when trying to compile a simple hello world:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::wcout << L"Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and add an include directory from IDE in Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include  Directories or from command line with /I. this additional include directory shoudl contain a header file called "Math.h", the file can be empty.

I have not tested with other compilers/IDEs yet, and I am not motivated to use the latest version of VS as it contains a shtload of spyware aka "telemetry" etc.

Comment: In windows filenames are case insensitive, so for windows math.h and Math.h are considered equal file names. Try moving the Math.h file to a subdirectory of a directory in your include path and then use #include <mydir/Math.h>. Think of it as namespacing your header files.

Comment: `math.h` is the name of a standard header, you need to rename your header or put it in a sub folder (e.g. so you include `#include "mylib/math.h"`)

Comment: The TL;DR: _rename_ `Math.h` to something else. `math.h` (lowercase) is a standard `.h` that `cmath` is the C++ wrapper for. WinX file systems can be case insensitive so when looking for `math.h`, it may use your `Math.h` instead. Also, are you _redefining_ standard function names (e.g. `fabs`)?

Comment: @CraigEstey i am not using any standard function etc, the Math.h can be empty and no Math.c is included or something. dam guys looks like I am too old and I have forgotten basic things like this. thank you all

Comment: _Side note:_ It's unlikely you're older than me (sigh ;-). And, I still make mistakes every day. It takes a village ...

Comment: _"...can produce this problem when trying to compile a simple hello world:..."_ The sample code compiles clean for me live - https://godbolt.org/z/9xo9dK1EE .  Have you accidently edited one of the Standard or MS-Window headers ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I think they mean that the code doesn't compile when their custom `math.h` header is present on the include path